# Data Logging without Interfacing SD Card module

Tags: arduino-nano

I want to log data to a text document without connecting the SD card module. I don't want to print the data on Serial Monitor I want to store it in a file. Is it possible? Can someone help me with it?
I am using a Arduino Nano on a Windows 10 system, and I want to know if there is an Arduino library to write logs to a file.

Comment: That is a problem for Ubuntu system, I am currently working on windows. I want to know if there is an Arduino library to write data into a .txt file directly available.

Comment: read the up-voted answer

Comment: To a file that is stored on the PC the Arduino is connected to?

Comment: it your not going to put the data on the serial port, and your not going to have a local storage option(SD card) how do you expect the data to get to said text document?

Comment: maybe they have such an Arduino library at Hogwarts

Comment: @Gerben Correct

Comment: One option, which is doable, but not elegant, is to store data in EEPROM.  You can't store much data, but if you don't want to use an SD card, and you don't want to talk via the serial port (or use Bluetooth, other communication protocols), that might work.  Not pretty, but if you need to store only a tiny bit of data, that is an option.    Here's an example; https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2017/02/using-eeprom-to-store-data-on-the-arduino/   User Juraj made a reference to a duplicate question where someone else mentions this as well.

Comment: You're asking the impossible, you want to create a file without attached storage (no SD card) and without outputting the data (via serial) to be stored. How else do you expect the data to be sent from the Arduino to your file?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to install a program that handles serial connection and can write everything into a logfile. On Linux, CuteCom is a program like that. On Windows, putty can handle serial (as well as SSH and telnet), and has logging.

The more advanced soulution is to write a program (or a simple script) that can do that. You could make it to do some other stuff as well (like configuring the Arduino side), and you can run it in the background without user interaction.